# Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:javaPreCompileDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to run a code in debug mode, and getting this error.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'flutter_embedding_debug.jar (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-5babba6c4d25fa237bbf755ab85c9a0c50b3c6ec)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
 > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\SOLIC\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\flutter_embedding_debug\1.0.0-5babba6c4d25fa237bbf755ab85c9a0c50b3c6ec\b458081743a320c57c360e4b8260848b361cb59d\flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-5babba6c4d25fa237bbf755ab85c9a0c50b3c6ec.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: invalid entry CRC (expected 0xc5a5fb23 but got 0x3162074). (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

More info: [Please look into my github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67605#)

Comment: try flutter clean?

Comment: I tried ```flutter clean``` , reinstalling flutter, restarting IDE, and ```flutter pub cache repair```

Answer (score 2):

### First Option:

Upgrade your Flutter with

```
flutter channel stable && flutter upgrade
```

and then clean your flutter project and all the cache files with

```
flutter clean
```

and then run the flutter project:

```
flutter run
```

### Second Option:

Remove the proxy setting inside your

> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

### Third Option:

Add repository which is inside your

> app/build.gradle

**The Edit:**

```
maven {
    url 'http://download.flutter.io'
}
```

Comment: I uninstalled android studio, removed flutter sdk and dart-sdk and reinstalled everything, after a while everything worked fine. But before that I have tried the first and third options. Both didn't work, I did not try the second option though.